# Replacing similar characters in unix

Tags: shell, unix, awk

I'm using the following command

```
awk -f script.sh dictionary.txt "test.txt" >> "test2.txt"
```

to replace some characters in a .txt. My script is the following:

```
NR == FNR {
  rep[$1] = $2
  next
}

{
    for (key in rep) {
      gsub(key, rep[key])
    }
    print
}
```

and here's my dictionary:

```
I   0:maj[ |]*
i   0:min[ |]*
bII 1:maj[ |]*
II  2:maj[ |]*
ii  2:min[ |]*
bIII    3:maj[ |]*
III 4:maj[ |]*
iii 4:maj[ |]*
IV  5:maj[ |]*
iv  5:min[ |]*
V   7:maj[ |]*
v   7:min[ |]*
bVI 8:maj[ |]*
VI  9:maj[ |]*
vi  9:min[ |]*
bVII    t:maj[ |]*
VII e:maj[ |]*
vii e:min[ |]*
```

I'm facing two problems:

1) II (or ii, III, VI, etc) is not read as a distinct entity, but rather as two times I. How can I specify to my script that everything in the first column should be read as a "block" of characters. I tried using (), [], ""; nothing seams to work. I can use i{2} to distinguish ii from i, but I can't do it for something like vi.

2) The space character in the second column creates some issues. I tried escaping it, but it won't work.

Any tricks ?

[edit] Here's a sample of the .txt

```
I   ii  V   V   
I   II  V   V   
I   ii  IV  V   
I   ii  III IV  
I   ii  vi  IV  
I   ii  iii IV  
I   II  IV  V   
I   IV  I   ii  
i   ii  V   V   
i   ii  V   V   
i   II  V   V   
i   ii  iv  V   
i   ii  IV  V   
i   ii  vi  IV
```

Comment: What does `test.txt` look like?

Comment: There is no space character in the second column.  Rather, there are three columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an alternative with its sample output:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{k=$1; $1=""; r[k]=substr($0,2);next} {for (i=1;i<=NF;i++){if ($i in r) {$i=r[$i]}}} {print}' dictionary.txt "test.txt"
0:maj[ |]* 2:min[ |]* 7:maj[ |]* 7:maj[ |]*
0:maj[ |]* 2:maj[ |]* 7:maj[ |]* 7:maj[ |]*
0:maj[ |]* 2:min[ |]* 5:maj[ |]* 7:maj[ |]*
0:maj[ |]* 2:min[ |]* 4:maj[ |]* 5:maj[ |]*
0:maj[ |]* 2:min[ |]* 9:min[ |]* 5:maj[ |]*
0:maj[ |]* 2:min[ |]* 4:maj[ |]* 5:maj[ |]*
0:maj[ |]* 2:maj[ |]* 5:maj[ |]* 7:maj[ |]*
0:maj[ |]* 5:maj[ |]* 0:maj[ |]* 2:min[ |]*
0:min[ |]* 2:min[ |]* 7:maj[ |]* 7:maj[ |]*
0:min[ |]* 2:min[ |]* 7:maj[ |]* 7:maj[ |]*
0:min[ |]* 2:maj[ |]* 7:maj[ |]* 7:maj[ |]*
0:min[ |]* 2:min[ |]* 5:min[ |]* 7:maj[ |]*
0:min[ |]* 2:min[ |]* 5:maj[ |]* 7:maj[ |]*
0:min[ |]* 2:min[ |]* 9:min[ |]* 5:maj[ |]*
```

This approach handles dictionary values with a space in them or even if they have multiple spaces in them.

#### How it works

Taking each section, one at a time:

- `NR==FNR{k=$1; $1=""; r[k]=substr($0,2);next}`

  This creates a dictionary `r` from the `dictionary.txt` file.  The key is the first field.  The value is whatever is left of the line after removing the first field.  Removing the first field is done in two steps: (a) `$1` is set to the empty string, and (b) the spaces that follows the now empty `$1` is removed with the `substr` function.
- `{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++){if ($i in r) {$i=r[$i]}}}`

  This goes through each field in turn making the substitution.  Since the input is now treated like fields, rather than characters, a field such as `ii` will not be mistaken for two consecutive `i`s.
- `{print}`

  The full line, with substitutions, is printed.

#### The issue with `gsub`

The problem that you were running into was that the result was dependent on the order in which the keys are retrieved from the dictionary:

```
for (key in rep) {
  gsub(key, rep[key])
}
```

If, for example, `i` was retrieved before `ii`, then the input `ii` was treated as two consecutive `i`.

Comment: Great minds think alike! I was actually considering doing the same thing as you to get the key but it leaves an extra space before each value.

Comment: @TomFenech That is why I added `substr` to remove that space.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `gsub`, just go through each of your fields and do a straight swap:

```
NR == FNR {    
    rep[$1] = $2 " " $3
    next
}

{
    for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i) {
        if ($i in rep) $i = rep[$i]
    }
    print
}
```

Or if you prefer a one-liner:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{rep[$1]=$2" "$3;next}{for(i=1;i<=NF;++i)if($i in rep)$i=rep[$i]}1' dictionary.txt test.txt
```

The problem with your approach is that `ii` does match the regular expression `/i/` as well as `/ii/`, so `gsub` makes whichever substitution it encounters first in the array. With this approach you're swapping the value for the key that exactly matches. Note that I've changed the assignment of `rep` as well, to deal with the space in between `[ |]*` as awk treats these as two different fields.

Output:

```
0:maj[ |]* 2:min[ |]* 7:maj[ |]* 7:maj[ |]*
0:maj[ |]* 2:maj[ |]* 7:maj[ |]* 7:maj[ |]*
0:maj[ |]* 2:min[ |]* 5:maj[ |]* 7:maj[ |]*
0:maj[ |]* 2:min[ |]* 4:maj[ |]* 5:maj[ |]*
0:maj[ |]* 2:min[ |]* 9:min[ |]* 5:maj[ |]*
0:maj[ |]* 2:min[ |]* 4:maj[ |]* 5:maj[ |]*
0:maj[ |]* 2:maj[ |]* 5:maj[ |]* 7:maj[ |]*
0:maj[ |]* 5:maj[ |]* 0:maj[ |]* 2:min[ |]*
0:min[ |]* 2:min[ |]* 7:maj[ |]* 7:maj[ |]*
0:min[ |]* 2:min[ |]* 7:maj[ |]* 7:maj[ |]*
0:min[ |]* 2:maj[ |]* 7:maj[ |]* 7:maj[ |]*
0:min[ |]* 2:min[ |]* 5:min[ |]* 7:maj[ |]*
0:min[ |]* 2:min[ |]* 5:maj[ |]* 7:maj[ |]*
0:min[ |]* 2:min[ |]* 9:min[ |]* 5:maj[ |]*
```